# How to replace missing value in a dataframe with an equation in python

Tags: pandas, function, replace, linear-regression, missing-data

I have the table below, where the missing values ​​in columns Bird1 and Bird2 must be replaced by the result of the linear equation `Y(X) = aX + b`, where "a" and "b" are constants.

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 33 | `X0` |
| `NaN` | 4 | `X1` |
| 3 | `NaN` | `X2` |
| 1 | `NaN` | `X3` |

The result should be as per the table below. How to implement this code in python?

| Bird1 | Bird2 | Bird3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 33 | `X0` |
| `aX1+b` | 4 | `X1` |
| 3 | `aX2+b` | `X2` |
| 1 | `aX3+b` | `X3` |

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```py
# define a and b constants, ex.
a = 10
b = 5

df.Bird1.fillna(a*df.Bird3 + b, inplace=True)
df.Bird2.fillna(a*df.Bird3 + b, inplace=True)
```